# How to add id field to a URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add a field (see "id" in the link below) to make a Ruby request to the Google shortener API.

https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Would I do this?

```
 request.add_field('id', '')
```

Or this

```
request.body = {'fields' => 'id', 'longUrl' => url, 'key' => 'kjdflsakjfslkf334'}.to_json
```

HERE is the code. Not sure if the above is how I add id to the fields in the url?

```
  require "net/https"
  uri = URI.parse('https://www.googleapis.com')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/urlshortener/v1/url")
  request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  request.body = {'longUrl' => url, 'key' => 'kjdflsakjfslkf334'}.to_json
  response = http.request(request)

  d = JSON.parse(response.body)

  return d['id']
```

=================

UPDATE: I changed the code per a suggestion below (url). And I am now getting a different error.

```
        LogEntry.record(User.root_user, "The url inside and before shorten is: #{url}", LogEntry::ADMIN, url)
  require "net/https"
  uri = URI.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url')

  # Full control
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  request.body = {"fields" => "id", "longUrl" => url, "key" => "IzaSc8"}.to_json
  response = http.request(request)

   LogEntry.record(User.root_user, "The request sent to google shorten is : #{request.body}", LogEntry::ADMIN, request.body)
  d = JSON.parse(response.body)
  LogEntry.record(User.root_user, "The url inside shorten after google shorten is : #{d}", LogEntry::ADMIN, d)
  return d['id']
```

NEW ERROR (yes I am passing over my key that I enabled):

{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp"=>"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."}}

Comment: Have you tried hitting the endpoint from something like postman to test the request format?  request.body = {'fields' => 'id', 'longUrl' => url, 'key' => 'kjdflsakjfslkf334'}.to_json will give you the the following params <base_url>?fields=id&key=kjdflsakjfslkf334&url=url

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form("/urlshortener/v1/url", 'fields' => 'id', 'key' => 'kjdflsakjfslkf334')
```

Nice blog post here: http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html that shows long and short forms...

Comment: What do I do with this line then?    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/urlshortener/v1/url")

Comment: updated answer... check out that blog post.  My goto post when I can't remember this stuff

Comment: No it is not my real key.